# When consuming a WCF service, what are the pros and cons to referencing the data contracts directly vs via the WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl, poco

We have a WCF service that is composed of three different assemblies:

1. Entity Layer (POCOs)
2. BL Layer (Business Logic & Data Access)
3. Service Layer (WCF)

When consuming the service, what are the pros and cons of referencing the entity dll directly vs creating the data contract from the service's WSDL?

Comment: Which of your three layers have your `ServiceContract`? I mean the interface and not implementation.

Comment: The Service Layer has both the interface and the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only use .Net on all clients then you might be better off just referencing the dll. WSDL can work well if you have non-.Net clients that cannot reference the assembly, or you have .Net clients that cannot do it for various reasons (e.g. security).

Comment: What if we have a mix? Currently, all consumers are .NET and are projects which we control directly. In the future, it is planned to consume these services using Java based clients. Would it make sense to have the .NET clients reference the POCO assembly directly and have others access them via the WSDL? Are there any disadvantages to this?

Comment: In this case I would suggest to use WSDL also in .Net so you would have a single consumption path to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

**Refence via WSDL**

*Generated* DataContracts provide implementation for two interfaces automatically.

- INotifyPropertyChanged - which is generally used for binding to data (WPF/Silverlight). So, you get this out of the box if you want to use the objects in your View/ViewModel.
- IExtensibleDataObject - used to maintain [version compatibility without loosing data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx). This is useful if you'd have clients with older version of your proxy and want to talk to newer version of the service and such scenarios.

**Directly reference Entity Layer assembly**

Say you split your business layer into two assemblies - server and client. You want to use the client business layer on the client obviously. However, both service and client business layer assemblies have reference to Entity Layer assembly.

In this case if you generate DataContracts from WSDL, they will be different types (although with same class name) and you wont be able to easily use them with the client business layer assembly. Here it could possibly make more sense to add reference to your entity layer assembly and while generating proxy, you should choose to re-use types from referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing business logic on the client side for example. If you add a property containing an aggregate of other properties, you can let the client use that property when required, instead of always sending it over the wire.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you please provide a simple example?